# Use custom folder instead of ~/.aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I want to find a way to not have to specify `aws_access_key` and `aws_secret_key` when use aws modules.

Is that aws default try to use credentials in `~/.aws` to run against playbooks?

If yes, how to instruct ansible to use aws credentials under whatever folder you want, e.g: `~/my_ansible_folder`.

I ask this because I really want to use ansible to create a vault: `cd ~/my_ansible_folder; ansible-vault create aws_keys.yml` under `~/my_ansible_folder` then run playbook `ansible-playbook -i ./inventory --ask-vault-pass site.yml` that will use aws credential in the vault that I don't have to specify `aws_access_key` and `aws_secret_key` in tasks.. that need to use aws credentials.

Answer (score 1):

The list of [boto3 configuration options](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#configuring-credentials) will interest you, most most notably the `$AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` environment variable.

I would expect you can create that shared credentials file using a traditional `copy: content="[default]\naws_access_key_id=whatever\netc\netc\n"` and then set the `ansible_python_interpreter` fact to be `env AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/path/to/that/credential-file /the/original/ansible_python_interpreter` to cause the actual python invocation to carry that environment variable with it. For non-boto modules, doing that will just cost you running `env` as well as `python`, but to be honest the bizarre module serialization and deserialization that ansible does anyway will cause that extra binary runtime to be invisible in the scheme of things.

You may have to override `$AWS_CONFIG_FILE` and `$BOTO_CONFIG` in the same manner, even pointing them at `/dev/null` in order to force boto to not look in your `$HOME/.aws` directory

So, for clarity:

```
- name: create our boto config
  copy:
    content: |
       [default]
       aws_access_key_id={{ access_key_from_vault }}
       aws_secret_access_key={{ secret_key_from_vault }}
    dest: /somewhere/sekrit
    mode: '0600'
  no_log: yes
  register: my_aws_config

- name: grab existing python interp
  set_fact:
    backup_a_py_i: '{{ ansible_python_interpreter | default(ansible_playbook_python) }}'

- name: patch in our env-vars
  set_fact:
     ansible_python_interpreter: >-
         env AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE={{ my_aws_config.path }}
         {{ backup_a_py_i }}

# and away you go!
- ec2_instance_facts:

# optionally put this in a "rescue:" or whatever you think is reasonable
- file: path={{ my_aws_config.path }} state=absent
```

Comment: I'm new to ansible so I'd like to do a verbose and can you please help to confirm it? create a file with content of `[default] ... }}` to `/somewhere/sekrit` with `no_log` and save it to `my_aws_config` for use later. Set `backup_a_py_i` that is a path of `ansible_python_interpreter` if it exists, if not use path of `ansible_playbook_python`. Set `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` now to `my_aws_config.path` and followed by `backup_a_py_i` so boto would consult `my_aws_config.path` first. Is that all correct?

Comment: In case I have a tree of playbooks contains folder and subfolders, that calling each other, some call all, some call few playbooks. Where to put and run your playbooks so that I can safely use aws credentials later when deploy other playbooks?